# Cannot update Acquia Dev Desktop Drupal Core 7.61 to 7.65 through Drush

Tags: drush, acquia-dev-desktop

I did a brand new install of Drupal 7.61 using Acquia Dev Desktop 2. I selected a "Standard" installation profile after launching the site in a browser. I tried to update Drupal Core through the Drush console, and it's failing. Here is my Drush output:

```
C:\Acquia\Websites\drupal-7.61>drush vset --exact maintenance_mode 1
maintenance_mode was set to 1.                                                                                 [success]

C:\Acquia\Websites\drupal-7.61>drush cache-clear all
'all' cache was cleared.                                                                                       [success]

C:\Acquia\Websites\drupal-7.61>drush pm-update drupal
Update information last refreshed: Thu, 03/28/2019 - 08:38
 Name    Installed Version  Proposed version  Message
 Drupal  7.61               7.65              SECURITY UPDATE available


Code updates will be made to drupal core.
WARNING:  Updating core will discard any modifications made to Drupal core files, most noteworthy among these are .htaccess and robots.txt.  If you have made any modifications to these files, please back them up before updating so that you can re-create your modifications in the updated version of the file.
Note: Updating core can potentially break your site. It is NOT recommended to update production sites without prior testing.

Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The paths must be strings. Got: NULL' in                      [error]
C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\webmozart\assert\src\Assert.php:1181
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\webmozart\assert\src\Assert.php(195):
Webmozart\Assert\Assert::reportInvalidArgument('The paths must ...')
#1 [internal function]: Webmozart\Assert\Assert::string(NULL, 'The paths must ...')
#2 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\webmozart\assert\src\Assert.php(1115): call_user_func_array(Array,
Array)
#3 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\webmozart\path-util\src\Path.php(855):
Webmozart\Assert\Assert::__callStatic('allString', Array)
#4 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\webmozart\path-util\src\Path.php(855):
Webmozart\Assert\Assert::allString(Array, 'The paths must ...')
#5 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\includes\filesystem.inc(588):
Webmozart\PathUtil\Path::join(NULL, 'drush-backups')
#6 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\includes\filesystem.inc(602):
drush_preflight_backup_dir(NULL)
#7 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\commands\pm\version_control\backup.inc(80):
drush_prepare_backup_dir(NULL)
#8 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\commands\pm\version_control\backup.inc(23):
drush_version_control_backup->prepare_backup_dir()
#9 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\commands\pm\updatecode.pm.inc(199):
drush_version_control_backup->pre_update(Array, Array)
#10 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\commands\pm\updatecode.pm.inc(82): _pm_update_core(Array,
'C:\\Users\\10admi...')
#11 [internal function]: drush_pm_updatecode('drupal')
#12 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\includes\command.inc(422):
call_user_func_array('drush_pm_update...', Array)
#13 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\includes\command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array,
Array)
#14 [internal function]: drush_command('drupal')
#15 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\includes\command.inc(199):
call_user_func_array('drush_command', Array)
#16 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\includes\command.inc(55): drush_dispatch(Array, Array)
#17 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\commands\pm\pm.drush.inc(1361):
drush_invoke('pm-updatecode', Array)
#18 [internal function]: drush_pm_update('drupal')
#19 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\includes\command.inc(422):
call_user_func_array('drush_pm_update', Array)
#20 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\includes\command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array,
Array)
#21 [internal function]: drush_command('drupal')
#22 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\includes\command.inc(199):
call_user_func_array('drush_command', Array)
#23 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\lib\Drush\Boot\BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
#24 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\includes\preflight.inc(66):
Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#25 C:\Acquia\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\drush.php(12): drush_main()
#26 {main}

C:\Acquia\Websites\drupal-7.61>
```

Again, this is a brand new site just installed. I was able to put the site into maintenance mode (verified through a web browser) and clear all cache. How do I fix this error?

UPDATE (03/29/2019): I am using Drush version 8.1.17. I am using default PHP v5.5.38. I tried to use the recommended PHP v.7.2.13, but when I tried to run the `drush pm-update drupal` command, it did not see a new drupal core update.

Comment: I also tried using just “Minimal” install instead of “Standard” and got the same error.

Comment: I have similar issues with a fresh ADD install, but assumed it has something to do with my environment...

Comment: Run `drush status` or at least tell us which version of Drush you are using - and PHP version. (I don't have time to (re)install ADD to test myself.)